# How to assign value from one field to another field in other object in Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I would like to delete object (one row in table) after click `Delete` button(ever row has delete button.

How to assign `th:object="${userToDelete}"` with proper row in table: logical this operation `UserToDelete.id = user.id` ?

```html
 <form th:action="@{/admin/showUsers}" th:object="${userToDelete}" method="post">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      </tbody>
      <tr th:each="user : ${users}">
       <td style="color: #000000" th:text="${user.id}">id</td>
       <td style="color: #000000" th:text="${user.name}">Name</td>
       <td style="color: #000000" th:text="${user.email}">Email</td>
       <td>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" value="Delete"
            class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary btn-block">
        </div>
       </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the usage of th:object. It is used to define a bean inside form tag and allow the use of th:field to navigate the property of the object defined. Back to your question, I see your form action is reserved for the user detail page instead of deletion. So you may create a javascript function which accept the selected ID when you press the delete button then prompt a message to ask for confirmation before deletion and then submit with that ID as parameter to your deletion endpoint URL.

Comment: Do I have to use javascript? A wanted use "pure" Thymeleaf.
User story:  I see a table of users. One user is represented by a row in the table. Every row includes a Delete button. After click Delete button I see the same table minimize about chosen row.
Now I don't want prompts a message.
I want to pass value id from List of Users(users)(for particular user) to id from userToDelete. How I can achieve this: (userToDelete.id = user.id)

Comment: Please consider what @Chris says. You totally misunderstood the usage of `th:object`. For deletion; you should be constructing an **anchor (link)** instead of a button. And then you can use a *Get Request* to hit a *Get Mapping* in a *controller* with the delete logic. Your link should be like `<a href="@{/admin/users/delete/${user.id}}" >`

Comment: I can't believe it was so easy. 
Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add `td` for every `tr` :

```
<td>
   <a th:href="${'/admin/delete/' + user.id}">delete</a>
</td>
```

Then add `GET` endpoint for delete - `/admin/delete/{id}`

Answer (score 0):

These are the possible solutions:

1. Add a `GET` endpoint for delete with `@RequestParam`; e.g.:

   ```
   <a th:href="@{/admin/user/delete(id=${user.id})}">delete</a>
   ```

   (As [suggested by Ahmet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54693546/how-to-assign-value-from-one-field-to-another-field-in-other-object-in-thymeleaf/54725534#comment96200274_54693546).)
2. Add a `GET` endpoint with `@PathVariable`; e.g.:

   ```
   <a th:href="${'/admin/delete/' + user.id}">delete</a>
   ```

   (As [suggested by idan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54718810).)